# Powerpoint table size from Matlab

Tags: matlab, vba, powerpoint

I want to fill in a powerpoint (I'm working on 2007) table with data from Matlab (2010a).

For that, I'm using inside MATLAB:

> ```
> % Open powerpoint with handle
> ppH = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');
>
> % Add new presentation
> presH = ppH.Presentation.Add;
>
> % Add blank slide
> blankSlide = presH.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item(7);
> slideH = presH.Slides.AddSlide(1,blankSlide);
>
> % Create 10x5 table
> tableH = slideH.Shapes.AddTable(10,5,10,10,200,200);
> ```

Ok so, now I want to change cell's height and width. I've tried so far with no success:

> ```
> tableH.Table.Cell(1,1).Shape.Width = 95;
> tableH.Table.Columns(1).Shape.Width = 95;
> tableH.Table.Columns(1).Width = 95;
> tableH.Table.Cell(1,1).Parent.Columns(1).Width = 95;
> slideH.Shapes(1).Table.Columns(1).Width = 95;
> ```

Do you know how to do this?

DBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running with:

> ```
> tableH.Table.Columns.Item(1).Width = 95;
> ```

Where Item(i) denotes the ith column.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This works in PPT 2010 where the table OM is semi-broken.  Whether it'll work in PPT 2007 where the table OM is a trainwreck is another story.  If it doesn't set the first column of the currently selected table to two inches (144points) wide, it's likely due to PPT bugginess.

```
Dim osh As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Set osh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
Set oTbl = osh.Table

With oTbl
    .Columns(1).Width = 144
End With
```

Comment: Your solution is similar to tableH.Table.Columns(1).Width = 95; since oTbl is a table. I don't have Office 2010 here to test it though.. but thanks